# Introducing someone in writing

Tags: pronouns

While writing the biography of a person, can we use the second person pronoun to introduce him?

> Your name is John and your title is the Lion.

In the English language, I don't know if this way is allowed. In some other languages e.g. Arabic, Urdu, and Hindi, this way is used, though.

Or will it sound odd? So we need to use the 3rd person pronoun?

> His name is John and his title is the Lion.

Comment: It would be extremely unusual. I think most readers would find it odd to read a biography addressed to its subject (who knows about their own life already!).

Comment: My answer is "probably not", but it might depend on the context. What specific kind of biography is this. "Biography" can refer to many things (not just a factual academic book about someone's life), and there may be a context where second person is OK (e.g. in giving a eulogy, a speech praising someone's life, or another address where it is implied that the person can hear.)

Answer (score 2):

In a formal business context, such as in a proposal or on a company website, a biography typically uses the third person to describe the person or to describe yourself if it's your bio. For example:

> John Smith is the president of ABC, Inc, where he oversees the operations of the company. John graduated summa cum laude from Harvard University and was president of his fraternity. He enjoys skydiving and cliff diving in his spare time.

Comment: I don't think you meant to say people use the third person to write autobiographies. Was that your intent?

Comment: It depends on context; often you would use the first person for an autobiography (whether in a book or in a textual introduction e.g. an election communication, or a speech), but sometimes the third person is more appropriate, especially in a formal/academic/business context where you avoid the first person.

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect that this is the business use.